# How to check if set A is subset of set B in R?

Tags: r, set, subset

I have two sets A and B. I want to check if set A is a subset of set B. I have tried I am aware of the set operation in R. I have tried intersect, union, setdiff. However, non of them were helpful. For example,

```
A = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

`B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

I am looking for a function that returns TRUE or FALSE. 
I have used `A %in% B` and compare the sum and length, which does the same job. But I feel like there is a beter way of doing this.

`length(A %in% B) == sum(A %in% B)` returns `TRUE` and 
`length(B %in% A) == sum(B %in% A)` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I was not able to find the previous question. Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 28):

We can use `all` with `%in%`

```
all(A %in% B)
#[1] TRUE

all(B %in% A)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way around, to check if `A` is a subset of `B`

```
setequal(intersect(A,B), A)
# [1] TRUE
```

to check if `B` is a subset of `A`

```
setequal(intersect(A,B), B)
# [1] FALSE
```